# jqGrid editoption values overriding selectoption values

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following column in my jqGrid:

```
{ name: 'Active', 
index: 'Active',
width: '55',
align: 'center', 
formatter: 'select', 
editable: true, 
edittype: "select", 
editoptions: { value: { "1": "Yes", "0": "No" }}, 
stype: 'select', 
searchoptions: { value: { "": "All", "1": "Yes", "0": "No" }} 
},
```

**The problem is that the editoption values are overriding the searchoption values (so "All" is not showing up as an option in the search toolbar).**

**I am using jqGrid 3.5.3.** I am not allowed to update to a later version.

If it helps, here is the whole table declaration:

```
mygrid = jQuery("#GridView").jqGrid({
url: 'Handler.ashx',
datatype: "json",
colNames: ['ID', 'Active Flag'],
colModel: [
    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: '45', formatter: 'integer' },
    { name: 'Active', index: 'Active', width: '55', align: 'center', formatter: 'select', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: { "1": "Yes", "0": "No" }}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: { "": "All", "1": "Yes", "0": "No" }} },
],
rowNum: 50,
height: '403px',
rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
 sortname: 'ID',
pager: jQuery('#PageNavigation'),
sortorder: "asc",
viewrecords: true,
caption: "Tasks",
toolbar: [true, "top"],
editurl: 'Handler.ashx'
```

I also tried setting both editoptions and searchoptions to have the same values (All, Yes, No) and then using an onSelectRow function to change the editoptions after the fact, like this, but it didn't work:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    jQuery('#streamGridView').setColProp('Flag', { editoptions: { value: { "1": "Yes", "0": "No" } });
}
```

How do I fix it so I can have differing edit and select values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only by chance I found the source of jqGrid 3.5.3 in my archive. The retro version of jqGrid don't get any values from `searchoptions.value` at all.

I'd recommend you to insert `<option value="">All</option>` **manually** in the select *after* the filter toolbar is created. The corresponding code could be

```js
$("#gs_Active")
    .prepend("<option value=''>All</option>")
    .val("");
```

The above code add the option `"All"` to the filter toolbar over the column `Active` and then select it.